# MySql delete query is too slow and runs forever

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL table (TABLE1) with 400 thousand records

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukey1` (`VALUE`,`NAME`,`UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukey2` (`UID`,`NAME`,`VALUE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `TABLE2` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE3ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FKEY` (`TABLE3ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKEY` FOREIGN KEY (`TABLE3ID`) REFERENCES `TABLE3` (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `TABLE3` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TYPEID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The following query is very slow and takes hours and finally fails

```
delete from TABLE1 t1 
inner join TABLE2 t2 on t1.UID=t2.UID
inner join TABLE3 t3 on t2.TABLE3ID=t3.ID  
where t3.TYPEID in (234,3434) t1.USER_ID is not null and t1.USER_ID <> '12345';
```

Visual explain shows the following and adding index on UID not helping. How to optimize the performance of this query?

[image]

- I tried adding an index on TABLE1.UID
- Converting into a subquery
- A simple query like `SELECT * FROM TABLE3 where UID="SOMEUID"` takes 800+ ms to fetch data

Comment: Use a `JOIN` rather than `WHERE UID IN (subquery)`. I've found that MySQL implements the latter very inefficiently.

Comment: Please add the exact MySQL version and the subquery too. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any indices on the table? Having an index on (UID) would be useful; an index on (UID, USER_ID) could be even better.

Comment: @AleksG The indexes are shown in the question. He said that adding an index on UID didn't help.

Comment: There's already an index on UID, since it's a prefix of the `ukey2` index.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I have updated the question with details that were omitted for brevity

Comment: How many rows in each table?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to a JOIN.

```
DELETE t1
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT uid FROM ...) AS t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
WHERE USER_ID is not null and USER_ID <> '12345';
```

I've found that MySQL implements `WHERE uid IN (subquery)` very poorly sometimes. Instead of getting all the results of the subquery and looking them up in the index of the table, it scans the table and performs the subquery for each row, then checks if the uid is in that result.

Comment: Thanks, In fact, it was JOIN. I omitted for brevity. Updated the question

Comment: The main issue seems to be TABLE1 with 300K records and the table has UID column of varchar(255)

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a backup of that table this is the first rule for doing a delete queries or you can ruin it and take all the precautions that you considere before

( uid1,uid2,...uid45000)

What is the meaning of those values between the parenthesis ? Are you need to compare in the list all the UID values or some of them?

beacause you can avoiding put all the UIDS manually like this.

delete from TABLE1 where UID in (SELECT T.UID FROM TABLE1 as T where T.UID is not NULL and USER_ID <> '12345');

Before to doing this please check what do you want between the parenthesis and run the command in a TEST environment first with dummy values

Take in consideration that you have in the table varchars types in the UIDS field and thats the reason that this operation take a lot of time more than if you are using integer values

The other way is that you need to create a new table and put the data that you need to store for the old table, next truncate the original table and reinsert the same values of the new table to the old table again

Please before to run a solution check all your restrictions with your teamates and make a test with dummy values

Answer (score -1):

I would split your uid filter list in chunks (100 by chunk or other, need to test) and iterate or multithread over it